# Sample Employee SQL Server database with data

Tags: sql-server, sample-data

Hi I need some sample SQL Server Employee database with data such as id, surname, name, age, adress etc. It must be quite big, I search with google, but I don't find any good sample.
Can any body help ?

Comment: This question would be on-topic at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

The only tool I can think of is [Red Gate Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_data_generator/index.htm).

Otherwise, you'd be looking at someone's actual data or expecting someone to provide such a tool free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it a challenge to find such a database, privacy concerns prevent most publication of personal data such as you require.  You may find one using pseudo-data, that is data that looks like what you want but is not about 'real' people.  But you will probably find it easier to generate your own such pseudo-data.  If you take this approach you can be sure that the data you generate meets your requirements too.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be Employee based, but is definitely worth having a look

[AdventureWorks](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AW2008Details&referringTitle=Home)

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to Microsoft Visual studio for Database professionals it has a data generator built in which you can use
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833256(VS.80).aspx)

Also the AdventureWorks db also has a Employee table i think.

Answer (score 1):

The Northwind database contains some sample employee data in a .mdf file which can be attached to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The old Northwind database has Employee table but that's quite small.